# What is the best way to stream StarCraft 2 in justin.tv?

Tags: starcraft-2, streaming

I have a 12mbps download and 2mbps upload connection with AT&T u-verse, so I'm sure I'm able to broadcast with a pretty decent quality. Anyway. I've searched around on Google, but some methods are too complex, others are not very effective, others I get a black screen when I broadcast, etc. I'm looking for the simplest most effective method I can find. Hopefully someone here can help out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest application I've ever used for streaming games onto uStream (and I'm sure it would work fine on Justin.tv) is a program called [WebcamMax](http://www.webcammax.com/). I was able to install and have a stream running in minutes with little to no configuration. I think I actually spent more time on uStream messing with their stuff than the application.

The streaming options are simple and easy to use. You can quickly switch between your webcam, your desktop, the application, or a specific area of your monitor. Then hop on Justin and it should detect your "webcam" and begin streaming the image to the site. It worked great when I used it for Team Fortress 2 (unfortunately my computer sucks now so streaming isn't really an option /cry).

Hope that helps!